# Input a UDF formula in a range with VBA

Tags: vba, excel, formulas

I have the UDF `Test(rng as range)` and I want to do something like this:

```
Dim rng2 as Range
Set rng2 = blah blah
rng2.formula = "=test(rng)"
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if `rng` is on another sheet? Then you need this:

```
rng2.Formula = "=test('" & rng.Parent.Name & "'!" & rng.Address & ")"
```

Comment: I would definitely choose this answer.

Comment: Just an observation: if the OP wants to insert the function via code, probably he doesn't refer to any `ActiveSheet` in particular. I would remove the `If` check and simply refer to the parent names of both `rng` (input) and `rng2` (output).

Comment: @MatteoNNZ wouldn't be any point for `rng2` as we're dealing with the object directly - agreed there's no need for the `ActiveSheet` check as the address will still work with the sheet name even if it's on the same sheet so can be reduced to just one `IIf()` statement. Will update when I get back to a computer!

Comment: Right for the rng2, I agree with this simple change you said.

Comment: @S O Yep this works as a charm.I used this just before I saw your edit.Thumbs up.

Answer (score 1):

The range address must be passed as a variable, not a string:

```
Dim rng2 as Range
Set rng2 = blah blah
rng2.formula = "=test(" & rng.Address & ")"
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the address of range i.e :

```
rng2.formula = "=test(" & rng.address & ")"
```